# MaterialCardView: Can't set checked state in xml layout

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, materialcardview

Android Studio 3.6

In xml layout I has this:

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/cardPaymentCardView"
                style="@style/cardViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:checkedIcon="@drawable/ic_credit_card_outline_select"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

To turn on/off checked state I use this (in my acitivity)

```
dataBinding.cardPaymentCardView.isChecked = !dataBinding.cardPaymentCardView.isChecked
```

and it's work fine. Nice.

But I need to set checked status direct in xml. Smt like this:

```
android:checked_state="true"
```

but I get compile error

Comment: "Cards implement Checkable, a default way to switch to android:checked_state is not provided. Clients have to call setChecked(boolean). This shows the app:checkedIcon and changes the overlay color." from [MaterialCardView documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/card/MaterialCardView)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A default way of switching to checked state is not provided, clients have to call setChecked(boolean) on the card*

**Checkable Cards**

> Cards implement Checkable interface. In the default style, @style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView, the checked state shows a checked icon and changes the overlay color. A default way of switching to checked state is not provided, clients have to call setChecked(boolean) on the card. Setter for an OnCheckedChangeListener is also provided.

[MaterialCardView documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-card-view/)

Answer (score 2):

There is a method `toggle` for `MaterialCardView`.

Example:

```java
cardPaymentCardView.setOnClickListener {
    cardPaymentCardView.toggle()
}
```

Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/card/MaterialCardView#toggle

Comment: it is worked, but I tried the same code inside onLongClick listener not working